# MySQL left join with max id

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have a table called tbl_messages the containes messages. Each message has a value of 0 under MessageReply if it's the first message and a message id if it is a reply to another message.

I need to get for each root message it's data + the date of it's latest response.

I'm running the following SQL procedure:

```
SELECT 
    m1.*, m2.MessageID, m2.MessageDate 
FROM 
    tbl_messages as m1 LEFT JOIN tbl_messages as m2 
ON 
    m1.MessageID = m2.MessageReply 
WHERE 
    m1.MessageReply = '0' AND 
    (m1.MessageUser = '1' OR m1.MessageBusiness = '1') AND 
    m2.MessageID = (SELECT MAX(MessageID) FROM tbl_messages WHERE MessageReply = m1.MessageID) 
ORDER BY 
    m2.MessageID desc, m1.MessageID desc
```

My problem is the because of the last WHERE statement it doesn't return values from the left table that doesn't have values on the right table.

How can I solve it?

Comment: I suspect that this query is a little confused. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query?noredirect=1#comment391934_333952

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you write the statement in `WHERE` Clause, it will filter the whole query results.

And when you write that statement in `ON` Clause when joining left, it will only filter left joined table and result will be `NULL` values from secondary table if statement is not matched.

```
SELECT 
    m1.*, m2.MessageID, m2.MessageDate 
FROM 
    tbl_messages as m1 LEFT JOIN tbl_messages as m2 
ON 
    m1.MessageID = m2.MessageReply 
    AND
    m2.MessageID = (SELECT MAX(MessageID) FROM tbl_messages WHERE MessageReply = m1.MessageID)

WHERE 
    m1.MessageReply = '0' AND 
    (m1.MessageUser = '1' OR m1.MessageBusiness = '1') 
ORDER BY 
    m2.MessageID desc, m1.MessageID desc
```

Comment: That's unfair. I'll give you one update to compensate!

Comment: Besides you're query seems to be OK. Just explain why you moved that condition from WHERE to ON.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks, I've added some explanations too.

Answer (score 0):

If your id is incremental, you should be able to just use MAX() to get latest/highest date and id

```
SELECT 
    m1.*, 
    MAX(m2.MessageID) AS reply_id, 
    MAX(m2.MessageDate) AS reply_date
FROM 
    tbl_messages as m1 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_messages as m2 ON 
    (
        m1.MessageID = m2.MessageReply 
    )
WHERE 
    m1.MessageReply = '0' AND 
    (m1.MessageUser = '1' OR m1.MessageBusiness = '1') 
GROUP BY
    m1.MessageID
ORDER BY 
    reply_date DESC, 
    m1.MessageID DESC
```

If your id isn't incremental, you can join the table a 3th time, with a later response, and that row that don't have a later response is the latest reply.

```
SELECT 
    m1.*, 
    m2.MessageID AS reply_id, 
    m2.MessageDate AS reply_date
FROM 
    tbl_messages as m1 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_messages as m2 ON 
    (
        m1.MessageID = m2.MessageReply 
    )
    LEFT JOIN tbl_messages as m3 ON 
    (
        m1.MessageID = m3.MessageReply AND
        m3.MessageDate > m2.MessageDate
    )
WHERE 
    m1.MessageReply = '0' AND 
    (m1.MessageUser = '1' OR m1.MessageBusiness = '1') AND 
    m3.MessageReply IS NULL
GROUP BY
    m1.MessageID
ORDER BY 
    reply_date DESC, 
    m1.MessageID DESC
```

You may want to COALESCE in your order by, to get the messages that don't have a reply, to end up where you may want them, like:
`ORDER BY COALESCE(m2.MessageDate, m1.MessageDate) DESC`